# magento shopping cart multiple rules on same product

Tags: php, magento

basically I have got 2 shopping cart rules, one is for 2 quantities of an item give it 10% discount, and the other one is for 10 quantities of this same item give it 20% discount. I have playing around with Priority and Stop further processing on both rules but I don’t seem to get it to give me the right results.

I am guessing the right way of doing it is to set the bigger quantity rule, 10 in this case, to priority 1 and the other to 2 with Stop further processing.

Any ideas?

Cheers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set up the 20% rule with stop processing and priority 1 (first to evaluate). You always want to give the best qualified discount possible.

Set up the 10% rule such that the quantity must equal 2 or more AND be less than 10. Otherwise it would not make sense for the customer.

Comment: Hey there, when I saw your answer I was, yess, but it is not giving me the results. By the way when you say AND be less than 10, is it on the "Maximum Qty Discount is Applied To" set to 9? If so not working. Will keep trying. Cheers

Comment: Yep, got it! Learned to leave alone "Maximum Qty Discount is Applied To" and "Discount Qty Step (Buy X)" and use quantity from conditions. Cheers